# Elasticsearch, disregard built-in mapping details in GET response

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch: v7.0 
Application: Laravel v5.8 
Using Elasticsearch/Elasticsearch (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) PHP Library

We were able to query more than 900,000 documents at a time and we are planning to optimize or to make our query faster.

We have observed that the built-in mappings details are always being returned with the response, (see image below)

[image]

**MAIN QUESTION** 
- Is there a way to disregard these mapping details, because we think somehow the response will be lighter if these details won't be included.

**SIDE QUESTION** 
- Or at least, may I humbly request anyone to educate me to optimize my Laravel-Elasticsearch application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disregard mapping details using `filter_path` which you can use for reducing the response returned by query.

e.g. if you hit:

```
GET geo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

You will get:

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 206,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "geo",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ALLE",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "dateFrom" : null,
          "aListRemoved" : [ ],
          "phone" : "0036-1-424-2242",
...
```

But if you use `filter_path`:

```
GET geo/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

You will get results without number of shards, hits relations, max_score etc:

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_source" : {
          "dateFrom" : null,
          "aListRemoved" : [ ],
          "phone" : "0036-1-424-2242",
    ...
```

Side question can't be answered simply because you need to describe what you want to do and what kind of queries are you planning to use. To skip scoring (if you don't need it) and improve performance, you could use `filter` and `constant_score` queries for example.

Some recommendations about tuning your `ES` cluster for search speed are described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html)

Comment: hello sir @Dejan thank you very much for the reply, appreciate it! I was able to do your suggestion in Kibana, however do we have any documentation of how to use that `filter_path` in Elasticsearch/elasticsearch PHP Library (the official library of Elasticsearch for PHP)

Comment: I'm not using PHP but maybe you can find more info here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/search_operations.html

Comment: thank you sir @Dejan, was able to omit unnecessary properties in the response just by using `filter_path`, appreaciate this one! :)